# Firebase security rules acting differently in v3

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-security

I am trying to prep some old apps for when v2 firebase is deprecated on dec. 18.  Firebase emails are saying only the auth will be deprecated but my AngularFire functions seem to not be working either because of the security rules.  For example -

```
$firebaseArray(ref.child('data').child('stuff')); <- used to work no problem
```

But now (v3) its saying that it doesn't have the right to access that data.

These are the firebase rules -

```
$company:{
".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('company').val() == $company || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('company').val() == 'COMPANY'",
```

however, if i just set both read and write to TRUE, it works again.

```
$company: {
".read": "true",
".write": "true"
}
```

$firebaseArray works but its getting tripped up on the security rules in ways it didnt before.  Any ideas on how I can adjust the rules to keep it all functioning the way it is supposed to?

now if i access the data using the v3 snapshot method, it works! but now its not synced with the data, its just a snapshot at that particular moment.  The reason i was using $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject is that it would sync with any changes on the db.

```
firebase.database().ref('/stuff').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('it worked!');
});
```

Thanks!

******************NEW EDITS*********************
12/14/18

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: APIKEY,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_URL, // Realtime Database
});

var stuffRef = firebase.database().ref().child('stuff');
var dataMaster = $firebaseObject(stuffRef);
```

**I get this error - ref.ref is not a function**

What am i doing wrong?? Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that changes on December 18 is that the old authentication endpoints stop working, The interpretation of security rules hasn't changed, nor will it change on December 18. 
---
I wrote up why the last snippet only fires once, but don't know why you see the other changes you describe. It's also hard to map the code (which accesses `/stuff`) to the rules you shared (which control access to `$company` somewhere in the JSON). Please make sure your question contains a [minimal, standalone, reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you're asking for help on.

Comment: hey @FrankvanPuffelen - thanks for the response.  Please check my edits in the question for the specific issue ive gotten it down to.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're using a version of AngularFire that is not compatible with the Firebase SDK you use.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You are right sir.  The app was from 2015 was on Angular Fire 1.1.2.  I upgraded it to 2.3 and it looks like its working now.

Comment: Good to hear. I updated my answer with that information too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any ideas on how to test if this app will work post Dec 18?

Comment: The best I can think of is checking what endpoints it's hitting, although I must admit I have no idea anymore what the v1/v2 endpoints were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185268/discussion-between-user3527354-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `firebase.database().ref('/stuff').once('value')`, the callback will be invoked only once (hence the name). If you want to get called with the current value *and* any updates to that value, use `on()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('/stuff').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('it worked!');
});
```

Note that the AngularFire version you use is quite old, so it may not work with never Firebase SDKs. In that case, consider also updating your AngularFirebase version.